# Programmatically fill one tableview, use IB bindings to fill others

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

A window is created in a xib, and it contains two tableviews, A and B. In interface builder, both A and B have the File's owner set as the delegate, since both will use some delegate methods, e.g. for drag and drop.

I would like to fill table A programmatically, i.e. using `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, but I would still like to fill table B using the *Bindings* tab in interface builder.

Is this possible directly?

It seems that in my case, having the delegate of both tableviews set to the file's owner will automatically mean that B is populated using delegate methods, overriding anything set in the IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that in my case, having the delegate of both tableviews set to the file's owner will automatically mean that B is populated using delegate methods, overriding anything set in the IB.

No, `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` and bindings work well together. Just do what the documentation says:

> It’s recommended that the implementation of this method first call the NSTableView method makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: passing, respectively, the tableColumn parameter’s identifier and self as the owner to attempt to reuse a view that is no longer visible or automatically unarchive an associated prototype view for that identifier.

> When using Cocoa bindings, this method is optional if at least one identifier has been associated with the table view at design time. (Note that a view’s identifier must be the same as the identifier of its column. An easy way to achieve this is to use the Automatic identifier setting in Interface Builder.)

Example:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if (tableView == self.tableViewA) {
        MyTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:myIdentifier owner:self];
        cellView.customView.data = myData;
        return cellView;
    }
    else {
        return [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:tableColumn.identifier owner:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I implemented `numberOfRowsInTableView` and the method you provided (with appropriate changes), and now table B is populated but the rows display empty strings (clicking the row still selects the correct data, as logging shows) 
- so, not as configured in IB. And table A is not populated at all. I guess my problem might be more specific/somewhere else.

Comment: So, in IB the column only contained an NSTextFieldCell - I changed that, and now your solution works for table A. For table B, however, it does not seem possible to set the values in IB, so I will resort to just setting them programmatically as well, meh.

Comment: Is the file's owner also the data source? Should work just as well. Bindings are difficult to debug, data source and delegate are easier.

Comment: It's both data source and delegate, for both of the tables. But I (we) figured it out now: The content bindings of the tables must be set to their respective arraycontroller (rather, their arrangedObjects). This was not necessary before, when both tables were populated from the xib